# Interactive Waypoint Follower Script in Navigation2 GPS Waypoint Follower Tutorial Not Fully Working for ROS2 Galactic?

Tags: gps, nav2, build-from-source, turtlebot-navigation, ros-galactic

I've been working through the [ROS2 Galactic Navigation2 GPS Waypoint Follower tutorial](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html)  but am facing issues specifically with running the **interactive waypoint follower script** (Step 3 of Tutorial). My setup involves building **SWRI tools from source for QoS compatibility** as explained here [QoS Compatibility Galactic](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/107599/issues-with-interactive-waypoint-follower-in-ros2-galactic-navigation2-gps-waypo), and I've made several modifications based on community suggestions for ROS2 Galactic.

**KEYS MODIFICATIONS AND STEPS**

1. **Built SWRI Tools from Source:** Due to QoS compatibility issues.
2. **Launched Mapviz Separately:** Using mapviz.launch.py.
   Inserted Bing API Key in Mapviz.
3. **Launched Robot Localization Separately:** Using dual_ekf_navsat.launch.py.
4. **Launched Waypoint Follower:** Launched only Gazebo, Sonoma world model, navigation stack, and RViz2  (**gps_waypoint_follower.launch.py**).

Launched Mapviz and Robot Localization Separately: I had to comment out mapviz.launch.py and dual_ekf_navsat.launch.py from gps_waypoint_follower.launch.py and launch them separately. Launching them together **prevented the map scenario from loading in Mapviz**, as also noted in [this issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2_tutorials/issues/73)

5. **Ran Modified Interactive Waypoint Follower Node:** Adjusted for ROS2 Galactic by removing the "basic_navigator" argument from BasicNavigator in interactive_waypoint_follower.py.
6. **Modified waitUntilNav2Active Function**: As per Steve's suggestion for [compatibility with ROS2 Galactic and older versions](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105711/nav2-interactive-waypoint-follower-example-can-not-get-robot-localization-state) of the nav2_simple_commander package. This modification addresses the robot_localization/get_state service issue in Galactic.

**CURRENT CHALLENGE**

Despite these adjustments, the interactive waypoint functionality **isn't working as expected**. After clicking a location in Mapviz to set a waypoint, **the red arrow does not appear, and the robot doesn't move**. The terminal shows **GPS coordinates** but no further action:

```
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705449673.656384722] [mapviz]: OK
[mapviz-1] [INFO] [1705449684.771503521] [mapviz]: Point in wgs84: -122.455,38.1615
```

Image from my attempt (GPS coordinates displayed when clicked on mapviz, any error log on terminal):

[image]

**QUESTIONS**

1. **Mapviz Interaction:** Is there a known compatibility issue with Mapviz and ROS2 Galactic that prevents waypoint command triggering?
2. **Tutorial Compatibility:** Are there known issues with completing this tutorial in ROS2 Galactic, specifically with source-built SWRI tools?
3. **Alternative Fixes:** Are there any known fixes or workarounds to get the tutorial running correctly in ROS2 Galactic, either from binaries or source builds?

Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to determine if this is a broader compatibility issue with ROS2 Galactic or if there are specific steps I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issues:

1. Teleop not working: I have installed **bcr teleop** for ROS2 branch:
   https://github.com/blackcoffeerobotics/bcr_teleop/tree/ros2

   git clone -b ros2 https://github.com/blackcoffeerobotics/bcr_teleop/tree/ros2
2. SWRI Tools, waypoint follower, mapviz, and other issues: I needed to create a new partition to install Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy and afterward install ROS2 Iron. Some methods were not implemented and are not fully integrated with ROS2 Galactic or Humble (Ubuntu 20.04). Therefore the only way I was able to fix the issues was **upgrade the ROS2 distro.**

Video of demonstration here: https://youtu.be/Hw4agX10k9s